# passing arguments to custom directive

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I'm having problems passing arguments to custom directive I wrote:

this is what I pass:
@renderblocks($deviceType, $subBlocksIds, $allBlocks)

first is just a string, second array of numbers and third an Eloquent array of models.

When I try to use the parameters well then I run into a problem:

```
    Blade::directive('renderblocks', function ($expression) {
        list($deviceType, $subBlocksIds, $allBlocks) = explode(', ', $expression);
        dd($deviceType);
```

it prints this -> "$deviceType" just like that and not actual string that the variable is holding. Same for other parameters, how can I pass parameters to custom blade directive and use them inside?

Answer (score 0):

Blade converts everything to `php tags` and replaces them into the file where you call the `directive`. You are trying to view the content of the variable in the `AppServiceProvider` which knows nothing about the `variable` but only sees it as a string.

Calling `renderblocks` in your view replaces it with what ever you return from the function. eg

```
Blade::directive('renderblocks', function ($expression) {
    list($deviceType, $subBlocksIds, $allBlocks) = explode(', ', $expression);
    return "<?php echo {$deviceType} ?>";
});
```

Replaces each call of `renderblocks` with `<?php echo $deviceType ?>`. This does not show any errors or show as a string because the variable `$deviceType` exist in that file. But you see it as a string in the `ServiceProvider` file because they are sent as strings and not the real variables.

You can work with the `variables` sent to the `ServiceProvider` and laravel would do its magic and send the returned results to the view.

Eg.

```
Blade::directive('addAge', function ($age) {
    $age= 999;
    return "<?php echo {$age} ?>";
});
```

calling `@addAge(1)` still shows `999` because it was changed in the `ServiceProvider` even though it was sent as a string